# Cheap Back up solutions with a public API

Tags: backup, web, api

I am looking for relatively cheap mass storage solutions like http://www.backblaze.com/ that has a public API.

We are currently using S3 but need to lower the costs.  This content will not be served but we may need it again in the future.

Thanks,

s

Comment: Dropbox has API. Are you looking for something like that? [Here are the pricing details](https://www.dropbox.com/plans).

Comment: Yeah, possibly, but I was looking for an unlimited solution with a public API.  the service we are running could have a couple of TBs pretty quickly.

Comment: Hmm. [Look at this list](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Storage). These are the online storage services with API. You can go through their websites to see if anyone fits you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look at this list](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Storage). These are the online storage services with API. You can go through their websites to see if anyone fits you.